# Why can't you define struct members globally?

Tags: c, struct

When you define a `struct` globally, why can't you define the structure members globally as well (outside of using the initializer syntax)? The error I'm getting from clang is that system_1 has an "unknown type name".

If you define the struct within a function, such as `main()`, then you don't run into any issues.

```
typedef struct Light_System {
    int redLightPin;
    int yellowLightPin;
    int blueLightPin;
} Light_System;

Light_System system_1;

# "Light_System system_1 = {4, 0, 0}" works

system_1.redLightPin = 4; # doesn't work

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    # placing everything in here works
    # placing just "system_1.redLightPin = 4;" here makes it work.
    printf("%d\n", system_1.redLightPin);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that I would be able to define the structure's members within the global scope.

Comment: Try this . Initialise a variable x in a global scope. `int x = 5;` then reassign its value `x = 10;` in a global scope and it will not compile. You can't assign values outside of functions. You can initialise values though.

Comment: I tried that and it did compile and work? Edit: I typed it in wrong, I see your point. Why is this?

Comment: Yes. It should not compile. Edit: I gave a small explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you define a struct globally, why can't you define the structure members globally (outside of using the initializer syntax)?

Because what you're trying to do is not a *definition* or an *initialization*. It's an *assignment*. You can declare, define and initialize in global scope, but not assign.

This is not only for structs. It goes for variables too. Outside a function, you can only declare and initialize variables. You cannot do regular assignments, or anything else for that matter. I'm not 100% sure of the details, but I'm fairly confident that you cannot do anything in global scope that cannot be done during compile time.

So this would work:

```
int x=5;
```

But not this:

```
int x;
x = 5;
```

Well, actually it is valid but will yield cryptic warnings about `warning: data definition has no type or storage class` and `warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘x’` However, just because it compiles, it will not do what you think it will. Actually, cryptic warnings that you don't understand is very often a good indicator that the code will do something that you neither want nor understand. What this code does is an *implicit redeclaration* of `x` followed by an *initialization*. It's allowed if it has not been initialized earlier, so this not valid:

```
int x = 3;
x = 5; // Not ok, because x is already initialized
```

And the error message here makes it clear why the previous example compiled: `error: redefinition of ‘x’`.

Similarly, this is not valid either:

```
int x = foo();
```

It gives this error:

```
main.c:3:7: error: initializer element is not constant
 int x = foo();
         ^~~
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated. You can not assign in a global scope. But you can initialise. So if you want to initialise struct members globally, you can try it like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Light_System {
    int redLightPin;
    int yellowLightPin;
    int blueLightPin;
} Light_System;
Light_System ls = {10,5,3};

int main()

{
    printf("%d %d %d",ls.redLightPin,ls.yellowLightPin,ls.blueLightPin);
}
```

That should compile.

So if you're wondering why this happens, it's because global variables are stored in the .data section of an application with a given value at compile time. But assignments are instructions which can only be executed within the scope of a function. So what gets compiled keeps their compile time value.

Comment: this should've been the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute statements outside of a function in C or C++.  But you can use C99-style "designated initializers" in a lot of compilers (not all):

```
Light_System system_1 = {
    .redLightPin = 4
};
```

This will become standard in C++20, but as the same syntax has existed for years in C, many compilers allow it in C++ as well.

Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization